# dejagnu scan-assembler regex

Tags: c, regex, assembly

I want to scan an assembly file with DejaGnu for:

**ld.h  %d2,**

But I can't explain the dot character and the numeric character.
I tried the following: (one backslash, two backslashes and bracketing)

```
/* { dg-final { scan-assembler-times "ld\.h\t%d\d," 1 { target { tricore-*-* } } } } */
/* { dg-final { scan-assembler-times "ld\\.h\t%d\\d," 1 { target { tricore-*-* } } } } */
/* { dg-final { scan-assembler-times "ld[.]h\t%d[0-9]," 1 { target { tricore-*-* } } } } */
```

1. The case with one backslash: it simply disappears, so the meaning of the regex is changing.
2. With two backslashes: it keeps both of them, so no matches during the scan.
3. With brackets: an error appears.

The output:

```
Running ../../../../testsuite/mytest/TX-1234.exp ...
PASS: testsuite/mytest/size16.c (test for excess errors)
FAIL: testsuite/mytest/size16.c scan-assembler-times \tld.h\t%dd, 1
FAIL: testsuite/mytest/size16.c scan-assembler-times \tld\\.h\t%d\\d, 1
ERROR: (DejaGnu) proc "." does not exist.
```

So, how do I explain the `\.` character or a `\d` decimal one?

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
(ld\.h \%d\d\,)
```

will validate ld.h %d2,
but you still have to check if it does not take wrong results in addition to all needed and tweek it if it is a case.
enjoy

Comment: This expression fails also. DejaGnu's parser is not a regular RegEx parser.

Answer (score 0):

The expression goes through a filter, so the right explanation of a dot character is `\\\.` ( `\\\.` -> `\.` ). The \d not works in DejaGnu. Use `\[0-9\]` instead ( `\[0-9\]` -> `[0-9]` ).